# Uncertainty proving statement via contradiction

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

If $a,b,c\in\Bbb N$ then at least one of $a-b$, $a+c$, and $b-c$ is even.

For the sake of contradiction, assume $a-b$, $a+c$, and $b-c$ are all odd. This gives us $a-b=2l+1$, $a+c=2m+1$, and $b-c=2n+1$ for $l,m,n\in\Bbb N$.

Now we have:

$\begin{align*}a-b&=2l+1\\a&=2l+b+1\end{align*}$

Substituting:

$\begin{align*}(2l+b+1)+c&=2m+1\\2l+b+c&=2m\\b&=2m-2l-c\end{align*}$

Substituting again:

$\begin{align*}(2m-2l-c)-c&=2n+1\\2m-2l-2c&=2n+1\\2c&=2m-2l-2n-1\\c&=m-l-n-\frac12\end{align*}$

But this is impossible for $c\in\Bbb N$, thus a contradiction and we are finished.

$\blacksquare$

I'm wondering if my reasoning is sound for this proof.. is there a simpler way I could have done it? Any advice welcome

Comment: If you add them all together you get $2a$ which is even.  An odd plus and odd  plus an odd is odd.   Indeed you must have either onee even and two odds or three evens.  But I'd prefer to read your proof than my argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

Here's any easier one: Suppose $a+c$, $a-b$, $b-c$ are odd. Then their sum is odd. This is a contradiction since there sum is $2a$, which is even.